How should I handle skill contests between two equally active participants?
I'm a GM who's considering transferring from D&D 5e to Pathfinder 2e. I understand that PF2e doesn't have contested rolls; instead, one character makes a check against the other character's DC. I'm unaware of standard terminology for these two roles, so I'll refer to them as "proactive" and "reactive", respectively, unless someone corrects me.
This approach to checks makes sense for most circumstances, but characters may occasionally engage in contests where they are equally proactive. (e.g. two characters entered a backgammon tournament and are now facing one-another) How should I assign the proactive/reactive roles in this case?
I could assign them arbitrarily, but that would advantage the proactive character because the base DC of 10* is lower than the mean dice roll of 10.5, and because matching the DC counts as a success. For two equally matched characters, this gives one a 10-percentage-point advantage over the other.

Have I properly understood the relevant rules? If so, then what's the proper, official, or otherwise best way to assign proactive & reactive roles in this situation?

*As an aside, is there any official explanation of why the base DC is 10? As far as I can tell, this problem could have been easily avoided by using a base DC of 11.

Victory Points
The Victory Points subsystem is the basis for many other subsystems. It is used to track progress toward a goal over the course of multiple rolls. This leads to less swingy results and allows for multiple participants.
Victory Points are often accumulated only by one side (typically the PCs), but the Multiple Point Subsystems section explains how opposing sides can compete to reach a goal:

In a multiple point subsystem, you have more than one point system, each measuring something different. For example, in a long-distance race, the PCs and their opponents both try to gain their own Marathon Points, and whoever gets to 10 points first wins!

A competitive game tournament example
First, set a point threshold that participants must reach. Somewhere around 3-5 VP is probably reasonable. More VP means more consistent results, but longer rounds can lead to boredom and dilute Hero Points.
Next, decide which skill will be used for "attack" and which DC will be used for "defense". Participants on both sides roll the "attack" skill (Society or Games Lore makes sense for a mental challenge) vs their opponent's defense (probably Will DC or Perception DC). Each side then gains VP based on their own roll. The first participant to reach the point threshold moves on to the next round of the tournament.
I would try to spice things up by having each NPC allow for the use of a different skill. You may be able to earn VP over a nervous opponent by using Intimidation. A wizard opponent may be easily distracted by nerd sniping them with Arcana. On the flip side, facing a ghoul opponent may be more about resisting their stench with your Fortitude DC rather than Will DC.
You'll need to decide how to handle both sides reaching the goal at the same time. Can a game result in a draw? Is there an overtime/sudden death ending?
Earning VP bit-by-bit allows you to ratchet up the tension. Maybe non-participating PCs can try to distract one of the participants (reflavoring Aid), or maybe the rules of the game change as time goes on.
An aside about DCs
When facing active opposition, I recommend using the opponent's skill DC, Perception DC, or save DC, or using a level-based DC.
A simple DC is better for challenges that don't actively oppose the PCs. When climbing otherwise normal ship rigging created by a legendary level 20 shipwright, DC 15 (the Trained simple DC) is probably more appropriate than DC 40 (the level-based DC for level 20), unless the shipwright is intentionally making it hard to climb.
